# How to use secure websockets with sock js

Tags: websocket, sockjs

I am using SockJS-client. SockJS constructor takes a relative URL as

```
var ws= new SockJS('/spring-websocket-test/sockjs/echo', undefined,{protocols_whitelist: [transport]});
```

Where do we indicate that WSS:// be used instead of WS://. If I try absolute URL, it gives error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ws://localhost:8080/appname/app. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
_ws_onclose. wasClean: false code: 1002 reason: Can't connect to server
```

Not sure why getting this error. Any similar configuration needed on Spring Server Implementation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Went through the sock JS client code :I went through the client code -sock JS takes care of it -if its HTTPS it uses WSS else it does  WS

```
var that = this;
var url = trans_url + '/websocket';
if (url.slice(0, 5) === 'https') {
    url = 'wss' + url.slice(5);
} else {
    url = 'ws' + url.slice(4);
}
```

No need to pass WS or WSS (In fact not even HTTP/HTTPS) with the SockJS constructor -just relative URL is sufficient. SockJs client library takes care of it.
One more surprising fact I encountered, it appends "/websocket" at end of the URL -this gave me clue why I was not able to connect with java client using jetty websocket-client apis

Comment: +1 for ur answer . It helped me. Also please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035552/sockjs-tomcat8-websockets-404-error?noredirect=1#comment46424068_29035552

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
var ws= new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/sockjs/echo', undefined,{protocols_whitelist: [transport]});
```

Comment: Its not about how to hit the server, that i can do with relative ULR -where do I specify WSS?

Comment: you must use http or htts instead of ws or wss.  
    new SockJS('HTTPS://' + window.location.host + '/sockjs/echo')
this code connects like 'wss://localhost:port/sockjs/echo'