# Sockjs + Tomcat8 websockets 404 error

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, websocket, socket.io

I have developed a plain **native websocket** + **tomcat 8** websocket sample appliation works fine.

But when I use the **sockjs.js** , instead of native websocket , I genting **404** error .

I am getting error in my browser console as

***GET http://localhost:8082/WebsocketsWithFallback/websocket/DataPublisher/info 404 (Not Found)***

Here is my javascript code,

```
var ws = null;
var sessionId = null;
var target = "/WebsocketsWithFallback/websocket/DataPublisher";
var connectionLive = false;
var init = false;
var pageCount = 0;
var delay = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

        if(sessionId == null && init == false){
            sendSessionId( $.trim($('#init').val()) );
        }
});


function sendSessionId(session){
    init = true;
    sessionId = session;
    // console.log("sessionId :"+sessionId);

    if(sessionId != null ){
        connect();
    }
}

function connect() {

    try{

        if(connectionLive == false){
            updateTarget(target);
        }

        if(ws == null){

            try{
                ws = new SockJS(target);
            }
            catch(e){
                alert("WebSocket connection error :"+e.description);
                setTimeout(function(){ connect(); }, 5000);
                return;
            }
        }

        try{

            ws.onopen = function () {
                console.log('Info: WebSocket connection was opened.');
                initMessage();
                connectionLive = true;
            };

        }
        catch(e){
            alert("WebSocket connection open error :"+e.description);
        }


        try{
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                // console.log('Received: ' + event.data);
                //Process the data to UI
            };
        }
        catch(e){
            alert("WebSocket message send error :"+e.description);
        }

        try{
            ws.onclose = function (event) {
                console.log('Info: WebSocket connection closed, Code: ' + event.code + (event.reason == "" ? "" : ", Reason: " + event.reason));
                ws = null;
                setTimeout(function(){ connect(); }, 5000);
            };
        }
        catch(e){
            alert("webSocket connection closed Error :"+e.description);
        }
    }catch(e){
        alert(e.description);
    }

}

function disconnect() {
    if (ws != null) {
        ws.close();
        ws = null;
    }
}

function sendData(message) {
    if (ws != null) {
        // console.log('Sent: ' + message);
        ws.send(message);
    } 
}

function updateTarget(val) {
    var target = window.location.host + val;

}


//Send initial message to pass parameters
function initMessage(){
    if(ws != null){
        ws.send(sessionId);
    }
}
```

My server side will be,

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/DataPublisher/")
public class Test {


    @OnMessage
    public void pushData(Session session, String msg, boolean last) {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg, last);

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void openWebSocket(Session session) {
        // My stuff
    }

    @OnClose
    public void closeWebSocket(Session session) {
        // My stuff
    }

    @OnError
    public void errorWebSocket(Throwable exception,Session session) {

    }

}
```

Please give any ideas or suggesstions.Thank you.

Comment: please chec the url  {get} http://localhost:8082/WebsocketsWithFallback/websocket/DataPublisher/info to  http://localhost:8082/WebsocketsWithFallback/websocket/DataPublisher {remove info}

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I am appending the **info** at the end of the url . **sockjs** automatically appending this .

Comment: Then ServerEndpoint  need to change

Comment: I cant't figure it out. Can u help me to solve. Can u post an answer ?

Comment: if u can share the code somewhere I can quickly deploy and verify in tomcat .. Info is appended by SockjS to verify what all protocol is supported by server (No need to explicitly add it as u mentioned) --something like this .. {"entropy":340346221,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":false,"websocket":true}

Comment: `@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/DataPublisher/")` change this to `@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/DataPublisher/info")` and test it once

Comment: I already tried this. But same error browser console